# \raggedouter to typeset marginal text in twoside book

Tags: horizontal-alignment, marginpar, tufte, ragged2e

We used the following code fragment using the [`changepage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package:

```
\newcommand{\raggedouter}{%
    \checkoddpage%
        \ifoddpage%
        \RaggedRight%
        \else%
        \RaggedLeft%
        \fi%
}
```

to provide a `\raggedouter` command, inspired by the `tufte-latex` class. Please see the following image to demonstrate the effect in a two-side book.

[image]

It is not uncommon and is done by Bringhurst's `The Elements of Typographic Style` or even in the German `Der LaTeX-Begleiter` by Mittelbach and Goosens. I would suspect the function in a package such as `ragged2e`. Does the upper code-fragment cover all possible cases? If there is a good solution, would it be an appropriate feature request for `ragged2e`?

Comment: Looks very good and yes could it makes a good feature request or patch the package yourself.

Comment: I want to add the following example to emphasize, that it is not limited to `\marginpar` per se: I use e.g. `\DeclareCaptionJustification{raggedouter}{\raggedouter}
\captionsetup{width=\marginparwidth, justification=raggedouter, font=footnotesize, skip = 0pt}` with the `caption` package.

Comment: Note: I had to use `\strictpagecheck` as well to get this working. Perhaps that's obvious for a non-newbie(?), but may be worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you for pointing at the use with captions, it was very helpful, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236026/how-to-align-captions-in-twoside-documents

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command `\marginpar` already does the check for odd pages or even pages, so it's simpler to say

```
\newcommand{\mymarginpar}[1]{%
  \marginpar[\raggedleft#1]{\raggedright#1}}
```

and to use `\mymarginpar` to insert marginal notes. Of course you can change `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` with the similar commands provided by `ragged2e`, if you think they are better for you.

You may want to load also `mparhack`, probably.

Comment: This was useful for me for a simple way to get "foot"notes to print in the margins with "correct raggedness" depending on recto/verso. The method above can be made to work seamlessly with `footmisc` if we redefine `\marginpar` itself (since `\footmisc[side]` uses that internally). In glorious compressed code: `\usepackage[side,flushmargin]{footmisc} \let\oldmarginpar\marginpar \renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]{\oldmarginpar[\raggedleft#1]{\raggedright#1}}` (useful to substitute for the `ragged2e` versions `RaggedLeft` and `RaggedRight`).

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the `raggedrightboxes` option of the `ragged2e` package? It *almost* achieves what you're looking for. :-) Unfortunately, there's no `raggedboxes` option, but that's easily fixed, as the remainder of this example explains.

Create a copy of the `ragged2e.sty` (which should be located under TEXHOME/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/) and name the new file (say) `newragged2e.sty`. The relevant lines of the package file are 84 to 115 (at least in my copy of the package). First, copy and paste this range of lines verbatim to immediately after this range. Next, change the first line,

```
\newcommand*{\@raggedtwoe@raggedrightboxes@opt}{
```

to

```
\newcommand*{\@raggedtwoe@raggedboxes@opt}{
```

and change the last line,

```
\DeclareOption{raggedrightboxes}{\@raggedtwoe@raggedrightboxes@opt}
```

to

```
\DeclareOption{raggedboxes}{\@raggedtwoe@raggedboxes@opt}
```

Third, replace the instruction

```
  \RaggedRight
```

located towards the end of the `\@arrayparboxrestore` command with

```
  \raggedouter
```

where `\raggedouter` is defined in your code example. (Note for readers other than the OP: the command `\checkoddpage` that is used in the definition of the `raggedouter` command is provided by the `changepage` package.) Run `texhash` (if needed) to make your TeX system aware of the new package `myragged2e`. Finally, load the `myragged2e` package with the `raggedboxes` option set, and you should be in business. :-)

Comment: And while your doing this, contact the author of `ragged2e` (me :) and pitch your idea.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Let me hereby pitch the idea of adding a "raggedboxes" option to the ragged2e package. :-) A different concern: While it may be worthwhile implementing an option to have all `marginpar` boxes be set RaggedRight/RaggedLeft, depending on whether they appear on recto/verso pages, providing an option that makes *all* boxes (incl. minipages, etc.) adhere to this style may be overkill. How providing an option "RaggedMarginpars" which affects only `marginpar` boxes and implements the OP's RaggedOuter idea, with RaggedRight in effect unless it's a two-sided document? Thanks.

Comment: And why is that better than the answer by egreg (`\marginpar`/`mparhack`) above?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I'm puzzled by your question -- where or when did I state that this suggestion was better than egreg's? I thought you were asking me a real question about my suggested solution, so I tried to provide further information what I was thinking about. If this was not the purpose of your question, I apologize sincerely for misunderstanding it. OK?

Comment: I'm asking because now I'm not convinced anymore that a raggedboxes option is needed.

Comment: The `\raggedouter` macro in `ragged2e` would give people more options. It is also defined in the `tufte-latex` package, that defines its own floats and does not use `marginpar`. Also, it is not a good reason, but `marginfix` has a bug that prevents me from using `/marginpar[\raggedleft]{\raggedright}` solution.