# How to align captions in twoside documents?

Tags: floats, sidecap, picins

While typesetting an illustrated book, I mostly use `SCfigures`. But in some cases I want the picture to be "wrapped" in the text, but with a caption on the side, so I use `picins` (see MWE below).

With `SCfigures` I can choose the options `innercaption` and `ragged`, so the caption will align towards the picture, nonetheless if it is on a left or a right page.

Why won't `piccaption` do this, or better, what will I have to do in order to have it do this? The `justification`-option of the `caption`-package doesn't help it even produces errors in combination with `sidecap`.

```
    \documentclass{scrbook} 
    \usepackage{
        graphicx,
        float,
        picins,
        wrapfig,
        lipsum}
    \usepackage[
        format=plain,
        singlelinecheck=false,
        skip=2mm,
        labelformat=simple,
        labelsep=newline,
        aboveskip=15pt
    %   justification=raggedright
        ]{caption} 
    \usepackage[
        innercaption,
        wide,
        ragged
        ]{sidecap}
    \sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}
    \listfiles

    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{SCfigure}[3][t]
    \caption{1st\\SCfigure\\picture right, ragged left}
    \rule{10mm}{4mm}
    \end{SCfigure}

    \pagebreak\lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{SCfigure}[3][t]
    \rule{10mm}{4mm}
    \caption{2nd\\SCfigure\\picture left, ragged right}
    \end{SCfigure}

    \pagebreak\lipsum[1-2]

    \piccaptiontopside
    \piccaption{3rd\\Caption of picins\\picture right, why not ragged left?}
    \parpic[r,t]{\rule{10mm}{4mm}}

    \pagebreak\lipsum[1-2]

    \piccaptiontopside
    \piccaption{4th\\Caption of picins\\picture left, ragged right}
    \parpic[l,t]{\rule{10mm}{4mm}}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Where is picins.sty?

Comment: Line 5 in the code-box. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I mean where can people answering find the `.sty` file itself?

Comment: The package is available at CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/picins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally found  a way: The Stackexchange-question

[\raggedouter to typeset marginal text in twoside book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32173/raggedouter-to-typeset-marginal-text-in-twoside-book)

provides a definition for "raggedouter" captions, I turned it into "raggedinner".

Thank you very, very much!

NB:
Be careful to use the right order
1. declare the command, 2. call the caption package, 3. declare the caption justification, and 4. use it in captionsetup:

```
\usepackage{changepage}
\newcommand{\raggedinner}{%
\checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage%
    \RaggedLeft%
    \else%
    \RaggedRight%
    \fi%
}
\strictpagecheck
\usepackage{caption} 
\DeclareCaptionJustification{raggedinner}{\raggedinner} 
\captionsetup{justification=raggedinner}
```