# Use the caption package together with sidenotes' marginfigure

Tags: floats, captions, margins, sidenotes

I am writing a document with margin figures, an environment that comes with [`sidenotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes).

I want to change the caption for those figures, with the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. But doing

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[marginfigure]{
labelfont=bf, % for example,
}
```

doesn't make the caption label in **bold**, and indeed the log tells me about it:

```
Package caption Warning: Unused \captionsetup[marginfigure] on input line 6.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

Is it possible to blend the `marginfigure` environment with `caption`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,sidenotes,caption}
\captionsetup[marginfigure]{
labelfont=bf, % for example,
}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum.
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Caption for the margin figure.}
\end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you come up with `\captionsetup[marginfigure]`? In the caption manual, I git zero hits for  `marginfigure`?

Comment: +1 For the good MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I just played with the code and googled a bit.
- To me, the relationship between the two packages is unclear, at least the manuals do not explain it very well (or I just did not find it).
- Inspired by [Change color for captions in sidenotes and alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394846), I came up with the following.
- **To be clear, I do *not* what I am doing here.**

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum.

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Caption for the margin figure.}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

[image]
*Taken from the **sidenotes** manual.*

[image]
*Taken from the **caption** manual.*